# 1 IV with two categories and 5 DV, which statistical test to choose?

Tags: t-test, multivariate-analysis, manova, variable

I'm wondering which statistical test to chose to find out which of my five DV is the difference between Country X and Country Y not statistically significant?

**My Variables are:**

**1 Independent variable:** Nation (Divided into two categories, Country X and Country Y)

**5 dependent variables sumscores** (comprised of different variables I have transformed into 5 different means)

Thanks beforehand!
 - And i'm sorry if its hard to understand me, English is not my native language

Comment: Where do the dependent variables come from? Are they aggregated across repeated measures? Is some information available about the variance of the estimates of your DVs? E.g., the question: "the moon is 400,000 km from the Earth and the sun is 150 million km from the earth. Is this difference statistically significant?" doesn't make sense without information about how accurately these distances are measured...

Comment: Hi Richard! Thanks for asking me to clarify I will try my best: N = 2900, homogenity of variance and assumption of normality reached. The DV's is based on a questionnaire where people from two different nations answered what they thought about: the United Nations (UN), the trust they have to their own government, their thoughts about immigration, how it affects their country and such. Then we made them into a mean sum for each of the five variables that clung together so the 5 DVs are: 1 Trust_international 2 trust_national 3 immigrant_open 4 immigrant_ consequence 5 immigrant_qualified

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that all the DV's have been measured on an ratio scale

Comment: See @amoeba's answer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82746/assessing-group-differences-on-multiple-outcomes and see if that answers your question